# OpenStreetMap editing problem

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to add a label (address) for building in OpenStreetMap.

[image]

I am editing the map by "Edit By ID" in OpenStreetMap Browser and saving it, but nothing is happening.

[image]

It only appear just a circle without an address when I click on "Map Data".

[image: ti]

Comment: Please provide a link to your changeset or the object or the area you are editing.

Comment: If you select that circle you will probably see the address that you added in the tags. The data layer does not render tags on the screen.  Address is still there in the data.

Comment: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/4.84992/31.59456&layers=D

Comment: Still not sure which object you are talking about. [This restaurant](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/7229793111/)? It renders for me, clear your browser cache if it doesn't for you. However you didn't add any address.